# Why are structures in the empty language non-empty sets?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

That's my question really.

Why sets, and why do they have to be non-empty?

How can an empty language have structures at all?

Comment: A structure by definition consists of a set, equipped with interpretation of each predicate/operation symbol. The empty language has no predicate/operation symbol, nevertheless the definition is valid, and all it remains is 'a set' (with an empty set of interpretations).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the definition is valid" please?

Comment: **def** a structure for a given signature (= collection of operation/relation symbols, with assigned arity) is $(M, F)$ where $M$ is a (sometimes required to be nonempty) set, and $F$ is a function that assigns an interpretation on $M$ to each operation/relation symbol. * This is perfectly valid even if there are no symbols in the language, whence $F$ is the empty function (a function with empty domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic statements are meant to be *about* objects. What objects?  Well, that's what a structure determines. But, in general, it's about *some* objects ... a 'bunch of' objects. So, a set works pretty darn well for that.

Why non-empty?  First, in *free logics* the domain can actually be empty.  But, you're right, we *typically* require the domain to be non-empty, i.e. be a non-empty set. This has some important practical consequences. For one, it makes many proof systems work. For another, you can infer $\exists x \ \varphi(x)$ from $\forall x \ \varphi(x)$. and finally, it is a pretty innocuous assumption to assume that your domain is non-empty. So, high benefit and low cost to assuming your domain is non-empty.

Finally, how does this the assumption of a non-empty domain square with an empty language? Indeed, how can we talk about anything at all with an empty language? Well, the first thing to note is that having an empty language does not mean that you don't have any symbols to work with at all. Indeed, the purely *logical* operators, like $\land$, $\neg$, and $\forall$ are always part of your language. It's just that there are non *non-logical* symbols, like $P$ or $a$.

In fact, we always have variables as part of predicate logic, and we would like them to have somethng to refer to, and a non-empty domian helps us to do so.

Also, remember that there is the $=$ (identity) predicate as part of the logical language as well. And, using that predicate, we can create statements to force the domain to contain certain specific number of objects, such as 'at least two', 'at most six', or 'either exactly four or exactly thirteen'. So, even with an empty language we can already force our domain to be a certain way.

Comment: Thanks. This helped! I have a follow up questions though. Since the empty language has no operation or relation symbols how is it that we can talk about formulas and assignment functions? I think my issue is that I'm struggling with the intuition for this level of abstraction.

Comment: @GGVeracruz Just added a bit to my Answer ...